# How do I move all the li elements with specific css style to another ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I need to move all of the `<li style="display:none;">` under a particular `<ul id="bob">` into a different `<ul id="cat">`.  In performing this move, I need all the classes, ids, and css styling to be preserved, and obviously the content as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy one-liner:

```
$('#bob > li:hidden').appendTo('#cat');
```

will move all `ul#bob > li` which are hidden, which is a superset of `ul#bob > li` which have `style="display:none;"`, since:

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS `display` value of `none`.
> - They are form elements with `type="hidden"`.
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector

---

If you **really** want **only** those elements whose `style` attribute is `display: none;`, I'd do it with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and a regexp:

```
var pattern = /^\s*display:\s*none\s*;?\s*$/gi;
$('#bob > li').filter(function ()
{
    return pattern.test($(this).prop('style'));
}).appendTo('#cat');
```

The regexp is case- and (mostly) whitespace-insensitive, and allows the semicolon to be optional, which is valid CSS. If you don't care about either of those you can git-r-dun with a one-liner, as before:

```
$('#bob > li[style="display:none;"]').appendTo('#cat');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cat').append($('#bob > li').filter(':hidden').remove());
```

Comment: That will completely lose non-hidden `<li>`s under `#bob`, which I don't think is what the OP wants. I could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bob li:hidden').remove().end().appendTo('#cat');
```